# Lubuntu 18.04 displays wrong lock screen after waking from sleep

Tags: login, lightdm, lock-screen

I have Lubuntu 18.04 installed on my laptop and I decided to install slick-greeter from the Ubuntu repositories. However, every after waking my laptop from sleep, this different undesired login screen appears instead. [image: Undesired lockscreen]

But it is supposed to be this one desired slick-greeter lock screen (image taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqM7hqfiCmc) [image: Desired slick-greeter lockscreen]

Strange enough, the undesired lockscreen only appears whenever I wake up my laptop from sleep. The desired lockscreen appears fine whenever I boot or whenever I logout from my user account. I already tried reinstalling `slick-greeter` and even `lightdm` but the problem is still present.

As far as I remember, the problem started when I updated the kernel to `4.15.0-39-generic` but I do not know if this has something to do with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have installed GNOME ScreenSaver. Remove it with:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-screensaver
```

---

The default Lubuntu 18.04 LTS installation uses `light-locker` ("simple screen locker for lightDM display manager").
You can install it with

```
sudo apt install light-locker
```

Comment: I did remove the undesired lockscreen by removing `gnome-screensaver`. However, I ended up having no lockscreen everytime the laptop wakes up from sleep. I am now having trouble on how to set `lightdm` as the lockscreen. I already tried reinstalling `slick-greeter` again but that did not work.

Comment: From default LUbuntu installation I see that is uses `light-locker`. Did you tried to install it with `sudo apt install light-locker`?

Comment: I already installed `light-locker` but it did not work. However locking the screen by typing `dm-tool lock` in the terminal indeed locks the screen with `slick-greeter`, so I'm now taking a different approach by executing the command `dm-tool lock` automatically whenever I close the lid.